# Высота ячеек GridView в android

Tags: java, android, gridview

Я задаю высоту gridview с картинкой вот так:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.AUTO_FIT, 100));
```

но на разных экранах высота ячеек отображается по разному.
Как с этим быть?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос программной установкой размеров gridview вот так:

LinearLayout.LayoutParams etParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(900,900);
gridview.setLayoutParams(etParams);